# Apply scale/location deforms mesh

Tags: mesh, scale

I'm a total beginner with Blender.
When importing my model to Unity3D, the rotation and the location of the body of the model is wrong.

I think I have to apply scale/location, but when I do that, the second I move the frame bar, the mesh deforms itself on Blender, and the location also changes back to some random numbers instead of staying at 0. When applying scale, the object goes super small (which seems quite strange).

After doing some research, it seems I should have applied scale/location/rotation before starting to animate (ups!). Is there any way I can unparent, apply scale/loc and then reparent while keeping the animation intact?

after applying location:
[image: after applying location]

after applying scale:
[image: after applying scale]

[image: on Unity3D]

[image: ctrljoined bones]

[image]

EDIT: finally solved the whole import to Unity3D thing by rigging the whole thing again, weight painting and animating while paying attention to all the points moonboots mentioned. Writing this for future reference: I think the key was re-rigging. Somehow Unity3D was understanding one of the main tentacle bones as the root node and that's why it was rotated in such a strange way (just like that specific tentacle bone).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the mesh only, open the *Dopesheet*, switch to *Action Editor* mode, click on *Only Include Channels Relating to Selected Objects* option, you can see that you've given your mesh an action called "Action". This action includes X, Y and Z scales that influence the scale of your mesh, and if you applied the scale it made your mesh smaller. You should not give any action to your mesh, only to the armature that controls this mesh, so just click on the X button to close this action. Also you should join the tentacle bones to the root bone to make it simpler.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot moonboots! Now I could apply scale/location/rotation without issues and everything's at 0, but unfortunately Unity is still importing the model with the rotation slightly off (added image of how it looks like), also, one of the tentacles is off too. By joining the tentacle bones to the root bone you mean ctrl+J them or parenting them?

Comment: yes ctrl J. About Unity, I can't tell, I don't know anything about game engines  :(

Comment: Ctrl-J'ing them makes the mesh go back to the "T-pose" (see updated new image). I have the feeling that the bones should be joined so that Unity will understand things properly but it's strange that it makes the mesh go back to that position :[ Thanks a lot for your help so far!

Comment: maybe instead of ctrl J, select the tentacle armature, deparent the tentacle armature from the single bone, delete the single bone, and in the tentacle armature create a single bone on the top that will be the parent of each first tentacle bone.

Comment: I tried that but it deforms the tentacles animation and mesh big time :/ (see updated new picture, I think the hierarchy should be ok now) and Unity still imports it super weirdly. I think at this point I'll just try to solve this programmatically somehow...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  It was related to the  material assigned.  What I ended up doing was removing the material,  then  I  applied  the  scale  (object=>Apply=>Scale).

Once this was done, I reapplied  the material and all was well.

I did this on Blender 2.9.1 on OS 11.